# MySQL Spatial for objects between two points?

Tags: php, mysql, geo

I am new to Polygons and Spatial and I code in php/MySQL

I am struggling with the right terminology to google.

There are lots of tutorials regarding items/places AROUND a lat/lng point and I am comfortable with that.

I want to learn how to locate items/places BETWEEN two lat/lng points within a rectangle.

Lets say I want to buy flowers on the way and direction to a friends house and I am happy to go off track by 1/4 of a mile, I don't want to go in the opposite direction.

Can someone give me the right terminology to use, so I can google some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

try spherical triangles. start here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html for definition. It's also called Spherical trigonometry or spherical geometry